# Pandas read_csv how to deal with sep character in parentheses

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, delimiter

So I have raw file like this with around 20k columns, similar to this:

```
number|colour|(a|1)|animal
1|green|x|dog
2|blue|y|cat
3|red|z|owl
```

when I use read_csv('raw.csv',sep='|') this creates a dataframe with an extra column becuase the (a|1) column gets split.

I tried to use the quotechar argument, but this can only take only one value. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948417/how-to-use-square-brackets-as-a-quote-character-in-pandas-read-csv) might be of help.

Comment: Something very particular to the data in your question would be `pd.read_csv('raw.csv',sep="(?<!a)\|(?!1)", engine='python')`. But I assume that your actual data may be more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

With the example data you have given, the extra seperator only appears in the header row. As such you could supply your own column names using the `names` keyword and then tell Pandas to skip the header row as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('raw.csv', sep='|', skiprows=1, names=["number", "colour", "(a|1)", "animal"])
print df
```

This would give you:

```
   number colour (a|1) animal
0       1  green     x    dog
1       2   blue     y    cat
2       3    red     z   owl
```